# angularjs material extra row and long word creates wrong layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i have following html in angularjs material:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
    
      <div layout="row" style="border: 5px solid red;">
        <div layout="column" style="border: 5px solid purple;">
          <div layout="row" style="border: 5px solid orange;">
            <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid yellow;">
              <md-content>
                LoremipsumdolorsitametnequodnovummeiSeaomniuminveniremediocrematinobortisconclusionemquenamNedelenitiappeterereprimiqueproinanilabiturdisputationitesedAtvixsaleomnesqueidprolabiturreformidansaccommodarecumlaboreshonestatiseuNecquemlucilasdasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaausineamraesentreformidansnoSedlaudemaliquamneaslkjaofiuhfsodbfsdlofdsoilisfdhbfdasofsdodsafhfsdlfsdfsdlkfdshldasfhlfasdkfsdlfdshfsldkhfdlfdksahfdlkfdshlsfdhkfdlfdsahfsdlkhfsdlfskdhlfsdkhfsdlkfhdslfdskhflkdslkhsafdhfslkdlsfhkd.
              </md-content>
            </div>
            <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid green;">
              Contact
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div layout="column" style="border: 5px solid purple;">
        <div layout="row" style="border: 5px solid orange;">
          <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid yellow;">
            <md-content>
              LoremipsumdolorsitametnequodnovummeiSeaomniuminveniremediocrematinobortisconclusionemquenamNedelenitiappeterereprimiqueproinanilabiturdisputationitesedAtvixsaleomnesqueidprolabiturreformidansaccommodarecumlaboreshonestatiseuNecquemlucilasdasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaausineamraesentreformidansnoSedlaudemaliquamneaslkjaofiuhfsodbfsdlofdsoilisfdhbfdasofsdodsafhfsdlfsdfsdlkfdshldasfhlfasdkfsdlfdshfsldkhfdlfd
            </md-content>
          </div>
          <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid green;">
            Contact
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Description of the situation:**

there are two blocks, the first containing my problem, the second working fine

the first one goes row>column>row>column(50%) | column(50%)

and a second one which does not contain the first row e.g.

column>row>column(50%) | column(50%)

the first of the 50% columns on each example contains a very long word.

**The Problem:**

In the first block the extra row seems to manipulate the layout in a way that the 50/50 rule does not apply anymore, since the block is not halved but instead the complete word is shown in the first 50% column whereas in the second block it works fine and the 50/50 rule is neatly applied and a scrollbar is shown in the inner md-content (or div).

**Question**:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I make the first block behave just like the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `.flex-100` / `flex="100"`to the container column for row 1.

The `.row` within it can't figure out a width for it without it defined, so will default to content width.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
    
      <div layout="row" style="border: 5px solid red;">
        <div layout="column" flex="100" style="border: 5px solid purple;">
          <div layout="row" style="border: 5px solid orange;">
            <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid yellow;">
              <md-content>
                LoremipsumdolorsitametnequodnovummeiSeaomniuminveniremediocrematinobortisconclusionemquenamNedelenitiappeterereprimiqueproinanilabiturdisputationitesedAtvixsaleomnesqueidprolabiturreformidansaccommodarecumlaboreshonestatiseuNecquemlucilasdasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaausineamraesentreformidansnoSedlaudemaliquamneaslkjaofiuhfsodbfsdlofdsoilisfdhbfdasofsdodsafhfsdlfsdfsdlkfdshldasfhlfasdkfsdlfdshfsldkhfdlfdksahfdlkfdshlsfdhkfdlfdsahfsdlkhfsdlfskdhlfsdkhfsdlkfhdslfdskhflkdslkhsafdhfslkdlsfhkd.
              </md-content>
            </div>
            <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid green;">
              Contact
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div layout="column" style="border: 5px solid purple;">
        <div layout="row" style="border: 5px solid orange;">
          <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid yellow;">
            <md-content>
              LoremipsumdolorsitametnequodnovummeiSeaomniuminveniremediocrematinobortisconclusionemquenamNedelenitiappeterereprimiqueproinanilabiturdisputationitesedAtvixsaleomnesqueidprolabiturreformidansaccommodarecumlaboreshonestatiseuNecquemlucilasdasdsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaausineamraesentreformidansnoSedlaudemaliquamneaslkjaofiuhfsodbfsdlofdsoilisfdhbfdasofsdodsafhfsdlfsdfsdlkfdshldasfhlfasdkfsdlfdshfsldkhfdlfd
            </md-content>
          </div>
          <div layout="column" flex="50" style="border: 5px solid green;">
            Contact
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```